# Windeployqt error: Unable to find the platform plugin

Tags: qt, deployment, plugins

I'm trying to deploy a program.

At first, I couldn't make the executable work outside of Qt. I put the folder `plugins/platform` and a bunch of dlls in the release folder where my executable is located, and now it works.

But I don't want to need all those files, I just want the executable so, I opened **cmd**, I went to the path of **windeploqt.exe** and typed:

```
windeployqt.exe C:\Users\pedro\Documents\build-Ejercicio_07-Desktop_Qt_5_14_0_MinGW_32_bit-Release\Ejercicio_07.exe
```

But I get this error:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.14.0\5.14.0\mingw73_32\bin>windeployqt.exe C:\Users\pedro\Documents\build-Ejercicio_07-Desktop_Qt_5_14_0_MinGW_32_bit-Release\Ejercicio_07.exe
C:\Users\pedro\Documents\build-Ejercicio_07-Desktop_Qt_5_14_0_MinGW_32_bit-Release\Ejercicio_07.exe 32 bit, release executable
Direct dependencies: Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Widgets
All dependencies   : Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Widgets
To be deployed     : Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Widgets
Unable to find the platform plugin.

C:\Qt\Qt5.14.0\5.14.0\mingw73_32\bin>
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: This is known bug in Qt 14 MingW64 [https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-80806](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-80806) , theck here for workaround  [windeployqt.exe with QT 5.14 Not copy the dlls](https://forum.qt.io/topic/109779/windeployqt-exe-comes-with-qt-5-14-not-copy-the-dlls-to-the-app-directory)

Comment: Qt 5.13 , MSVC2027 x64 bit config. same bug. Fix not applicable